# How to load 2 files in c++?

Tags: c++

This is cake.txt:

```
tiramisu;2;7;1;6;3;9;
strawberry with white chocolade;2;8;4;11;9;10;
creamcake;2;5;10;9;
chocoladecake;2;12;9;3;5;13;10;
```

and this is component.txt:

```
1;pepper
2;flour
3;sugar
4;chocolade
5;salt
6;eggs
7;caffe
8;butter
9;cheese
10;cream
11;strawberry
12;desiccated coconut
13;water
```

I want to display this files like this:

```
Cheesecake:
-butter
-cream
-cheese
```

Now  program display me such code: Cheesecake;2;3;7;5;
And this is my code

```
int Cake(const char* nazwaPliku)
{
    ifstream we;
    we.open(nazwaPliku);

    if( !we.good() )
    {
        cerr << "Problem with file read"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    string cak;

    while(getline(we,cak))
    {
        cout<<"Name cake: "<<cak<<'\n';

    }

    we.close();
}



int main()
{

 int name = Cake("cakes.txt");
 int names = Cake("component.txt");


    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how resolve second part this execise. I hope that someone show and explain me.

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you're trying to construct a recipe given a list of ingredients and which ingredient numbers are needed.

You can solve this problem by keeping a `vector` of all the possible ingredients in the order they are provided, then by accessing certain ingredients in the vector.

Here is my program which does this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream fin("component.txt");

    // store all the different ingredients
    vector <string> components;
    string temp;
    while(fin >> temp){
        components.push_back(temp.substr(2)); // ignore the first two characters
    }

    fin.close();
    fin.open("cake.txt");

    while(fin >> temp){ // input the next line
        string str;
        vector <int> semicolons;

        // find all semicolons; they separate the ingredients
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < temp.size(); ++i){
            if(temp[i] == ';'){semicolons.push_back(i);}
        }

        // "Cheesecake;"
        str.push_back(temp.substr(0, semicolons[0]+1);

        for(unsigned int i = 1; i < temp.size(); ++i){
            string num = temp.substr(semicolons[i-1], semicolons[i]-semicolons[i-1]);
            str.push_back(components[stoi(num) - 1]);
        } // "Cheesecake;milk;water;egg;"

        // "Cheesecake;milk;water;egg"
        str.pop_back();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP means. OP already reads both files.

Comment: Exacly, I have to change numbers from cake.txt to component from component.txt

Comment: Show me only name first cake without component

Comment: I do that in my program right after I open "cake.txt". The input string looks something like "Cheescake;2;3;5;7", so my program searches for the first semicolon in the input and then slices everything before it to get the name of the product.

Comment: The program should display name cake and change numbers on component. In file cake.txt cheesecake;2;3;5;7. This problem is : how to change numbers in file cake.txt on component from file component.txt. The program have to display: cheesecake:milk;water;egg for example

Comment: @Telescope: I don't think it's a good idea to write OP's program for him/her - it's an exercise.

Comment: It's any problem with "stoi"